# matrix multiplication mixup

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was watching a youtube video on linear algebra and it gave the following equality.
$\frac{1}{3}\left(\begin{matrix}1&2\\-1&1\\\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}4\\1\\\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}2\\-1\\\end{matrix}\right)$

I must be mixing up my basics of matrix multiplication, but when I try it I do not get the same answer. Is it possible to break down the steps of this multiplication to help with my understanding?

Comment: This is probably moot since your question appears to be satisfactorily answered, but in the future, adding your attempt (in this case, your attempt at multiplying the matrices) will provide valuable context and help answerers identify any specific issues you were facing in your understanding. A link to the YouTube video in this case might also be useful, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Brahadeesh Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac 13 \begin{bmatrix} 1\cdot 4 + 2\cdot 1 \\ -1\cdot 4 + 1\cdot 1\end{bmatrix} $$ $$= \frac 13 \begin{bmatrix} 6\\ -3\end{bmatrix}$$
$$= \begin{bmatrix} \frac 63\\ \frac {-3}{3}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$= \begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 \\
-1 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
4 \\ 1
\end{matrix}\right)
=
\left(\begin{matrix}
1·4+2·1 \\
(-1)·4+1·1
\end{matrix}\right)
=
\left(\begin{matrix}
6\\
-3
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Comment: error in the second row at the end.

Comment: @amWhy Whoopsie, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get the $(i,j)$ th element of the product matrix , multiply the $i$th  rows of the first matrix with the $j$th column of the second matrix just as in usual dot product of two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

We have $\left(\begin{matrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\\\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}c\\d\\\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}a_{11}c+a_{12}d\\a_{21}c+a_{22}d\\\end{matrix}\right)$  .

Answer (score 0):

We can first expand out $$\frac13 \left(\begin{matrix}1&2\\-1&1\\\end{matrix}\right)$$ as $$\left(\begin{matrix}\frac13&\frac23\\-\frac13&\frac13\\\end{matrix}\right).$$ We can than multiply the two matrices to get $$\left(\begin{matrix}2\\-1\\\end{matrix}\right),$$ as desired.

Comment: Your answer is (most likely) not useful. Burt's problem is precisely with the multiplication so saying " we can multiply the two matrices to get ..." is probably of no help to him.